# lookup and then filter the result, in mongodb node js monggose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to filter after `$lookup` in Monggodb, like giving where after join in sql.
can anybody please help? I have tried this so far:

```
orderHeader.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ids)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'orderstatuses',
      localField: 'order_status_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'orderstatus'
    }
  }
]);
```

I want to filter `orderstatuses.code=1`, if not 1 then do not show data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found simple solution using unwind, code bellow

```
orderHeader.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
                user_id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ids)
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup:{
                from:"orderstatuses",
                localField:"order_status_id",
                foreignField:"_id",
                as:"orderstatus"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind:{
                path: "$orderstatus",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
            }
        },
        {
            $match:{
                "orderstatus.code":1
            }
        },  
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
orderHeader.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ids)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'orderstatuses',
      localField: 'order_status_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'orderstatus'
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      orderstatus: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$orderstatus",
          as: "order",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$order.code", 1]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: with this code, if i change code 1 with 0, orderHeader still showing. Since in orderstatus collection 0 is not exist what i expect is data orderHeader also not showing, is any way to do that ?